# Propose an algorithm to find a "celebrity"

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, puzzle

A celebrity is a person that everyone knows, but he doesn't know anyone.

If we think of a group of people as a graph, where if there is an arrow from $A$ to $B$ that means "$A$ knows $B$", then a celebrity is a vertex of the graph that everyone is pointing to him, but he points to no one. Meaning if $C$ is a celebrity in a group of $n$ people:

$Deg_{in}(C)=n-1$, $Deg_{out}(C)=0$

This diagram shows it more clearly:

[image]

here $C$ is a celebrity. Obviously there can't be more than $1$ celebrity in a group of $n$ people, because if $C$ is a celebrity, then he does not point to anyone, specifically he does not point to $D$, so $D$ is not a celebrity because not everyone knows him ($C$ doesn't).

Propose an efficient algorithm, that runs in minimal steps, to find the celebrity (the star) in a graph with $n$ vertices.

The best solution I came up with is run through all the vertices and check if the current vertex is a celebrity. Checking if a vertex is a celebrity can be done in $\Theta(1)$, but we run through (potentially) all the vertices, so overall it's $\Theta(n)$ which is pretty bad.

I'm sure there is a better way, since suppose we started at vertex $A$ and it doesn't point to $B$. Then we don't need to check $B$ now. For sure it's not a celebrity.

Comment: Do you have an incidence matrix?

Comment: No, we are not given the incidence matrix. Suppose you were just handed a gigantic sheet of paper with a massive graph of $n$ vertexes and we want the celebrity

Comment: Then I choose a "people" at random then test all the "people" he "know" to see wich one is the celebrity. Work well if "people" knew few "people"

Comment: What is your proposed method Oria?

Comment: It's terrible. I propose checking each vertex for how many people know him and how many people he knows. run through the entire graph.

Comment: and hope i reach the celebrity sooner rather than later

Comment: Any of the graph search algorithms you already know, such as BFS, will find the celebrity, if there is one, in $O(n)$ time, and it is not possible to do better.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure the linear complete graph (tournament without cycles) cannot be solved with fewer than $n$ steps.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are at a vertex $X$ and $X$ is not a celebrity, you can remove from the search, not only $X$ but all vertices that know (point to) $X$. None of these are celebrities either. Therefore you only have to move to vertices that $X$ points to.

The best one can do in this problem is $O(n)$. Suppose that we have a $K_{n-1}$ where all edges point in both directions and a vertex $c$, the celebrity, to which all the vertices in the $K_{n-1}$ point to.

Given an algorithm $A$ that finds $C$ if $v_1\in V(K_{n-1})$ is the vertex that makes $A$ do the longest search, then $v_1\neq C$. By the symmetry of the graph this vertex is indistinguishable from all other vertices of the $K_{n-1}$. So, the algorithm gives the worst search for all vertices in the $K_{n-1}$. With the information in the vertex $v_1$ is not possible to detect where is $C$. Therefore in the worst search for $A$ it will move to some vertex $v_2$ of the $K_{n-1}$. We can remove the $v_1$ and its edges from the graph and we are in the same situation but with a graph with a $K_{n-2}$. By induction the worst search is $O(n-1)$ in that graph.

Comment: But if everyone know everyone (except the celebrity who know no one), it still take $n$ step at worse

Comment: Of course. In such a graph the non-celebrity vertices are indistinguishable. There is no way to avoid testing each of those vertices.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid doing $\Theta(n)$ steps in the worse case

Comment: No, that is the worst case.

Comment: If you mix your solution and Travi's you can tackle the graph where everyone knows everyone. take a vertex $v$. You only have to check people that don't know $v$ and that $v$ knows. Of everyone knows $v$. So we can be sure there is no celebrity.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream There is no difference between the "two" solutions. It is the same algorithm.

Comment: No they aren't, this algorithm can figure out there are no celebrities in the situation where everyone knows everyone in one step. The other one would take $n$ steps.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your set of possible celebrities to the whole set of vertices.

At each iteration, select a vertex from the set of possible celebrities.

If it is a celebrity, you are done.

If not, the list of celebrities is modified so that only people that your choice knows remain on the list.  (The celebrity must be known by your choice.)

Repeat

The algorithm runs very quickly if your first (or an early) choice has low "out-degree."

Comment: Keep in mind that not every graph has a celebrity.

Comment: true. We are not gauranteed that a celebrity exists

Comment: That's okay; this algorithm works if there is no celebrity. The list of potential celebrities might become empty, and if it does, you can halt immediately and report failure.

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine both the solutions we have? Start with a list of possible celebrity candidates $L$. At each step select a vertex $v$ from $L$ and check if he is celebrity, if not delete all the people from $L$ that $v$ does not know and all the people that know $v$. This algorithm seems rather good because it solves both the examples that are troublesome for the other two proposed algorithms in one step.

Comment: This graph fails against an ordered tournament though.